# Issue With name containing - in angular service

Tags: angularjs

I have a service like below

```
var places = [
      { "city" : "Bangalore","country-name": "India"},
      { "city" : "Mysore","country-name": "India"}
      ];

      this.getCities = function(){
        return places;
      };
```

I am calling the getCities in my controller and displaying the data in my html like below.

```
<li ng-repeat="place in places">
        <label>City : {{place.city}}</label>
        <label>Country : {{place.country-name}}</label>
        </li>
```

But the country name is coming as 0 and the city is working fine.

Please find the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CHcCR5zcVBo9AsNUON9B?p=preview) here

Please let me know why it is happening

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you assign the controller and service to a var?

Comment: In your plunkers scripts.js you have this( var MyService = function() ), is this a specific design/architectural pattern?

Comment: u mean I don't need the var or why i din define along with .service("MyService",MyService) line ?

Comment: yea, IMO if you were to define it differently you could have the functions from the service revealed much quicker. I just thought you did it for a specific reason.

Comment: Its the design style I am used to. thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `country-name` to `countryName`. You can't have dashes in your property names and then access them with the dot operator.

If for some reason you're consuming an api that you don't control, you can do this instead:

```
<label>Country : {{place['country-name']}}</label>
```